# How to implement a multi-source shortest path on unweighted graph using BFS?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I have a grid like this:

```
000000000
0AAA00000
0AA000000
0AAA00000
000000000
000000000
000000B00
00000BBB0
00000BBBB
```

Now how do I find the shortest path from A to B using BFS? the cost of traveling between A and A is 0 and A-0 or 0-B or 0-0 is one. 
I have tried applying BFS on each of the A individually and taken the minimum of that. But that doesn't seems to work. Is there any other approach?

Comment: You can begin from any `A`, right?

Comment: What you've done so far?

Comment: Try using Dijkstra algorithm starting from each 'A'. If you have problems to implement the algorithm come back.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using bfs?

Comment: Yes, just queue up all the starting nodes initially

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BFS will be okay. First you init the queue by all the positions of A in the grid. And each time, you pop a position at the front of the queue ,at the same time, push all the positions  which can be reached by 1 step and hasn't been visited yet. The first time you visit a B, you get the shortest path from A to B.

Answer (score 15):

A multiple-source [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) works in exactly the same way as regular BFS, but instead of starting with a single node, you would put all your sources (`A`'s) in the queue at the beginning. That is, make a pass over the grid to find all `A`'s and initialize your BFS queue with all of them at distance 0. Then proceed with BFS as normal.

Here's an example Python implementation:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import product

def get_distance():
    grid = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', 'A', 'A', 'A', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', 'A', 'A', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', 'A', 'A', 'A', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', 'B', 'B', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
    R = C = 9  # dimensions of the grid
    queue = deque()
    visited = [[False]*C for _ in range(R)]
    distance = [[None]*C for _ in range(R)]
    for row, col in product(range(R), range(C)):
        if grid[row][col] == 'A':
            queue.append((row, col))
            distance[row][col] = 0
            visited[row][col] = True
    while queue:
        r, c = queue.popleft()
        for row, col in ((r-1, c), (r, c+1), (r+1, c), (r, c-1)):  # all directions
            if 0 <= row < R and 0 <= col < C and not visited[row][col]:
                distance[row][col] = distance[r][c] + 1
                if grid[row][col] == 'B':
                    return distance[row][col]
                visited[row][col] = True
                queue.append((row, col))    

print(get_distance())  # 6
```